# Magento - Adding my own content block on home page only

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento-1.4, magento

This is just not working no matter what I try.

I've set up a new file at /app/design/frontend/mytemplate/default/template/page/popularsearches.phtml

I'm trying to reference in from the Layout Update .XML (from the CMS). The code i'm adding to the layout update xml , under the content reference looks like this:

```
<block type="core/template" name="popular_searches" as="popular_searches" template="page/popularsearches.phtml" />
```

Can anybody tell me why it's not working?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Ok I feel like an idiot now, but I've got this working, and I thought i'd post the solution incase anyone come here with the same problem.

I had set up my template file correctly, and the layout XML was all correct but I had not called the getChildHtml anywhere in a template to pull the content into a template.

To get it working I added the following to 1column.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('popularsearches') ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO!

There could be a few things going on. Assuming that your CMS page has `<reference name="content"><your block code from above /></reference>`, you've made your block a child of content, so it should render along with the rest of the content. By the way, you needn't give your block an alias (the as="" attribute).

1st step: You should refresh the Layout Cache under System > Cache Management.

2nd step: Check `var/log/system.log` and see if you are getting an **Invalid template** warning; typos/incorrect filepaths are often an issue. If your template isn't found, check your package and theme settings. By the way, it's entirely appropriate to add this *new* template under the base/default theme.

3rd step: If your template contains PHP, comment it out and see if you can get plain HTML to render. If so, there's a problem in your code. You can enable developer mode by adding `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` or altering the logic in index.php if you prefer. If this is a production box, obviously handle developer mode for your IP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ben.

The block is underneath the content reference yes.

1. Cache is turned off so no issue there
2. I turned on logging in preferences but it's still not created a var/log folder, so I'm guessing nothing is being logged?
3. Theres no php in my template file yet, just some html to let me know it works.

So basically, still stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

Since it's been 2 years since this was posted I'm sure you've figured this out by now, but could it be that you're using

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('popularsearches') ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('popular_searches') ?>
```

?

Your code in the Layout Update XML is specifying 'popular_searches' (without the underscore) for the name - not 'popularsearches'.

Answer (score 0):

You can add content by first creating a static block with your specific content and then calling the same through reference call in cms layout xml.

Search for  in cms block and set your content block under the same.

You may as well refer for reference http://prashantpandeytech.blogspot.in/2015/03/magento-add-seo-content-to-home-page-end.html